# make website width full on mobile platform

Tags: html, css

On our website: https://dev.shiftdivorceguide.com/ everything looks great on desktop.
When I switch to smaller screens like tablets I get a padding to the right of the screen. When I go even smaller (smartphones) I get an even larger padded area to the right of the screen.

I am unsure if the Panic Button bar at the top may be interfering with the code of the page (.panic-button-container). I have already tried altering the CSS in the media queries. To reduce the size of the white area on tablets I changed the code below concerning the logo and navigation widths.

I changed:

```
  @media (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 981px) {
     .header-right-panel {
        width: 40%;
        float: right;
     }
  }
```

to:

```
 @media (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 981px) {
  .header-right-panel {
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
  }
 }
```

This helped a little with the layout but I still get a white bar on smaller screens. The smart phones are the worst. Any possible solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing the "white area to the right of the screen" when I resize my browser or view it in a mobile layout using development tools

Comment: I think your problem is not the `.panic-button-container`, but you grid is messed up for your `.lp-section-row` that has the slideshow in it. This one doesn't have a `container` which might be the problem. Try commenting out or removing this section and see if the problem goes away

Comment: Your `.footer-menu` is also causing issues on small screens. Might want to look at that too

Comment: Personally I think the issue isn't in `.panic-button-container`. Deleting this element doesn't resolve the issue. The issue is that something else on the page is sticking out past the outer-bounds of the page, and expanding the window. As such, the `width: 100%` of  `.panic-button-container` is simply expanding to fill the space, rather than causing it.

Comment: The issue (or, *one* issue) is this div: `<div class="row lp-section-content clearfix">`, specifically the class `row`, which has `margin-right: -15px`. This is likely a bootstrap class that isn't properly contained, therefore it isn't "countering" the negative margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using floats. Use Flexbox. Too many clearfix divs in the way.

Obviously the footer is extending past the site content `body` as well as some other elements.

If you really want to narrow it down set this style:

```
 * { outline: 1px solid red }
```

That way you see what container is over-extending and then set it's width to 100% instead of a fixed width.

EDIT 2:

Using my technique I have narrowed down the problems:

```
.footer-menu
```

remove `width: 500px;`

```
.lp-section-content row
```

remove all negative margin

```
.vc_column-inner vc_custom_1548439628787
```

remove all `padding`

Comment: I'm not saying that floats are better by any stretch, but why "Stop using floats. Use Flexbox."? Why is this relevant, and why so absolute? Floats are less intuitive, sure, but just as capable when used properly (ie, clearing them). Also, resolving the footer issue still leaves a white gap.

Comment: Bc there are 30+ elements being floated and taken out of the flow on that page.  Often leads to unexpected results like this. And yes i absolutely am against floats in all situations.

Comment: The elements being floated are taken out of the flow as a result of them not being cleared, ie, they're being used incorrectly. I just don't think it's relevant to the answer and I think if you're going to claim such an absolute standpoint, you should explain why in your answer.

Comment: And then you will have 30 clearfixes... listen I get your point, it's not 100% relevant to the answer and people hate hearing absolute claims like this but the web would be a lot better place with no floats. Flexbox is supported everywhere and, talking about using clearfixes properly, if you coded your site properly with flexbox you wouldn' have this problem. So yes i'll advertise this idea wherever I can. Stop defending floats they don't have a time and place anymore.

Comment: Thank you, the tip about outlining everything in red is fantastic!